# How to override master

Tags: github, github-for-mac

I'm having some conflicts with the master as some people in my group have made changes that don't work and i changed. The problem is that github is not letting me override the master as there are too many conflicts in 2 of the files. How can I just re-write master completely.

Comment: If you really want to rewrite history and break everyone else, use `-f`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to completely overwrite the remote `master` branch with your current local `master` branch, and you are certain that this is the way to proceed here, then you can try the following:

```
git push --force origin master
```

However, I think a nicer way to handle this situation would be to have the people in your group who made bad commits *revert* (i.e. undo) those commits.  Ideally, they would be in a good position to know what needs to be changed.  To revert a commit, you can use:

```
git revert <SHA-1 of bad commit>
```

This will add a new commit on top of `master`, which effectively undoes a given bad commit.

Comment: Would this work if I uploaded to my own branch and then i want to over take the master branch? sorry a bit new to github

Comment: No, you probably wouldn't do it that way.  If you wanted to overwrite the remote `master` with your local branch (let's say it's called `your_branch`), you would use this: `git push --force your_branch:master`

Comment: To prevent this kind of issue in the future you may look into something like [branch permissions](https://help.github.com/articles/about-branch-restrictions/). Branch permissions let you configure what users are allowed to push to a branch (e.g. just you). Other users will need to open a pull request for review before users with push access merge the changes into your `master` branch.